# Pressing space bar causes sleep, and other weird things

Tags: firefox, windows-vista, keyboard, sleep

Wife called.  Our home "desktop" system (an HP box floor box maybe 6 years old running Vista) has started behaving strangely.  First "Windows Mail" started popping up when she tried to go to Facebook in Mozilla (we don't use Windows Mail at all).  Next, the box started going to sleep randomly, and she finally traced it to the spacebar.  And other weird things -- apparently, among other things, Google comes up with `,s` or some such in the search box.  (I have not yet seen these behaviors up close and personal.)

The box has a current version of Norton on it, and neither one of us is inclined to go to strange web sites, so the odds of an infection is pretty low.

Tried the usual things -- rebooting, clearing Mozilla cache, wiggling the (USB) keyboard cable, dropping the keyboard an inch.  Haven't yet played with any of the accessibility options, but will check those out.

But anyway, does this ring a bell?  (I'm planning to try a new keyboard, but don't keep a spare around anymore.)

**Minor correction**

The system is old enough that the keyboard has a PS/2 connector, not a USB.

**Update**

Got home and the wife reported that it seemed to be working, and had been working since she tried "exercising" all the keys.

I experimented a bit -- pressing the "Sleep" key on the left-hand side caused the box to sleep, just as the space bar had been doing, and pressing the "Mail" icon on the left side brought up Windows Mail.  Couldn't provoke a couple of the other behaviors she had seen, but it seems consistent with a malfunctioning keyboard -- something was mapping "normal" keys onto the left-hand keys (which we never use), and, likely, generating other spurious keystrokes as well.

Will keep an eye on it and update this question if there's anything new.

Comment: Sounds like windows thinks a key is stuck. I would start with restarting the system. If that doesn't help, check for any peripherals connected such as second keyboards, which has a key stuck on it. If that isn't the case, run a virusscan on the machine.

Comment: @LPChip - Yep, as I indicated we tried rebooting (from a cold start), and I had her pick up the keyboard and drop it (a fix that I've seen work on keyboards in the past).  It is kind of curious that when one puts the symptoms into Google you come up with a number of other HP boxes with virtually identical symptoms.

Comment: hotkeys are usually mapped to some arbitrary key combination, such as CTRL-ALT-WIN-1 or so. Something you normally never press. If windows for some reason thinks all modifier keys are stuck, just pressing that one activator key makes it work. So in your case, CTRL-ALT-WIN-SPACE would be mapped to the sleep button, and the CRTL-ALT-WIN keys were stuck. Of course, this was not your case, but then you get an idea of what I mean. Could be a virtual key as modifier that got stuck.